# create future dates in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a date column(date_1) in a pandas dataframe in YYYY-DD-MM.

```
  date_1
  2020-01-10
  2020-01-09
```

I want to add date_2 which is one month in future like

```
  date_1          date_2
  2020-01-11      2020-01-12
  2020-01-12      2021-01-01
```

I am using

```
 pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'],format='%Y-%d-%m').relativedelta(months=-2)
```

but its giving me an error as
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'relativedelta'
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'],format='%Y-%d-%m') + pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=1)
print (df)
       date_1     date_2
0  2020-01-11 2020-12-01
1  2020-01-12 2021-01-01
```

Comment: thanks...but while the year changes such as date_1=december 1st, it does not work....

Comment: @sayan_sen - Not understand. From sample data need add one month. Can you add some data which failed?